# TLS подключение

Tags: golang, tls

Есть сервер:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "crypto/tls"
    "crypto/x509"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net"
)

var sslkey string = "cert.key"
var sslcert string = "cert.pem"

//Прилетает сообщение
func handleConnection(conn net.Conn) {
    defer conn.Close()
    buf := make([]byte, 16384)
    for {
        _, err := conn.Read(buf) //размер сообщения
        if err != nil {
            if err != nil {
                log.Printf("server: conn: read: %s", err)
            }
            break
        }
        /*  tlscon, ok := conn.(*tls.Conn) //если тип такой
            if ok {
                state := tlscon.ConnectionState()        //возвращает основные TLS сведений о соединении.
                sub := state.PeerCertificates[0].Subject // цепочки сертификатов , представленный удаленный узел
                log.Println(":::::::::", sub)
            }*/
        conn.Write([]byte("PONG"))
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("server: write: %s", err)
            break
        }
    }
    log.Println("server: conn: closed ip:", conn.LocalAddr())
}

func main() {
    ca_b, err := ioutil.ReadFile("ya.pem")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(1)
        panic(err)
    }
    ca, err := x509.ParseCertificate(ca_b)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(2)
        panic(err)
    }
    priv_b, err := ioutil.ReadFile("ya.key")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(3)
        panic(err)
    }
    priv, err := x509.ParsePKCS1PrivateKey(priv_b)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(4)
        panic(err)
    }
    pool := x509.NewCertPool()
    pool.AddCert(ca)

    fmt.Println(pool)

    cert := tls.Certificate{
        Certificate: [][]byte{ca_b},
        PrivateKey:  priv,
    }

    fmt.Println("#Sert", tls.RequireAndVerifyClientCert)
    configg := tls.Config{
        ClientAuth:   4,
        Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert},
        ClientCAs:    pool,
    }

    configg.Rand = rand.Reader

    listener, err := tls.Listen("tcp", "192.168.0.130:8080", &configg)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer listener.Close()

    for {

        conn, err := listener.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(7)
            panic(err)
        }
        //      tlscon, ok := conn.(*tls.Conn) //если тип такой
        //      if ok {
        //          fmt.Println(522)
        //          state := tlscon.ConnectionState() //возвращает основные TLS сведений о соединении.
        //          fmt.Println(state.PeerCertificates)
        //          sub := state.PeerCertificates[0].Subject // цепочки сертификатов , представленный удаленный узел
        //          fmt.Println(544)
        //          fmt.Println(":::::::::", sub)
        //      } else {
        //          fmt.Println("!!!!!!", tlscon)
        //      }
        fmt.Println(5)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(8)
            panic(err)
            continue
        }
        fmt.Println(9)
        go handleConnection(conn)
    }
}
```

И клиент:

```
func main() {
    ca_b, err := ioutil.ReadFile("ya.pem")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(1)
        panic(err)
    }
    ca, err := x509.ParseCertificate(ca_b)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(2)
        panic(err)
    }
    priv_b, err := ioutil.ReadFile("ya.key")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(3)
        panic(err)
    }
    priv, err := x509.ParsePKCS1PrivateKey(priv_b)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(4)
        panic(err)
    }

    pool := x509.NewCertPool()
    pool.AddCert(ca)
    //fmt.Println(cert2_b)
    cert := tls.Certificate{
        Certificate: [][]byte{ca_b},
        PrivateKey:  priv,
    }
    fmt.Println(cert)
    config := tls.Config{
        ClientAuth:         4,
        Certificates:       []tls.Certificate{cert},
        InsecureSkipVerify: true,
        ClientCAs:          pool,
    }
    conn, err := tls.Dial("tcp", "192.168.0.130:8080", &config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("client: dial: %s", err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    //log.Println("client: connected to: ", conn.RemoteAddr())

    /*state := conn.ConnectionState()
    for _, v := range state.PeerCertificates {
        fmt.Println(x509.MarshalPKIXPublicKey(v.PublicKey))
        fmt.Println(v.Subject)
    }*/
    reply := make([]byte, 1000)
    //  log.Println("client: handshake: ", state.HandshakeComplete)
    //  log.Println("client: mutual: ", state.NegotiatedProtocolIsMutual)

    /************************ PING  ********************************/
    //verifyToken()
    message := "00:"
    n, err := io.WriteString(conn, message)
    n, err = conn.Read(reply)
    log.Printf("client: read %q (%d bytes)", string(reply[:n]), n)
    fmt.Println(111)
    return
}
```

Ключ сертификата и pem файл в бинарном виде: (Кусок)

```
2559 802b c383 d3b3 0043 d59f 3aa7 529d
13ed 6e63 24c0 0d6e c0c7 ada3 4af0 71d6
0d26 bfee 54bd e875 d165 05b0 8665 67b5
```

В итоге я получаю на сервере:"client didn't provide a certificate" 
Хотя пул сертификатов уже и там и там пробовал забить (хоть и на клиенте не обязательно). В чем еще может быть проблема?

Comment: Клиент не компилируется, `reply2 declared and not used`. Заодно рекомендую зачистить код от комментов и предоставить команды, которыми вы генерите `ya.pem` и `ya.key`.